# How can I continuously read a CSV file in Flink and remove the header

Tags: csv, datasource, apache-flink, pojo

I am working with Flink streaming API and I want to continuously read CSV files from a folder, ignore the header and convert each row in the CSV file into a Java class (POJO). After all this processing, I should obtain a stream of Java objects(POJOs).

So far, I do the following to partially achieve the behavior(code below):

- read the CSV files as regular text files, continuously
- get a stream of strings from the CSV files
- convert the stream of strings to a stream of Java objects

  ```
  String path = "/home/cosmin/Projects/flink_projects/flink-java-project/data/";
  TextInputFormat format = new TextInputFormat(
          new org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path(path));
  DataStream<String> inputStream = streamEnv.readFile(format, path, FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY, 100);

  DataStream<MyEvent> parsedStream = inputStream
      .map((line) -> {
          String[] cells = line.split(",");
          MyEvent event = new MyEvent(cells[1], cells[2], cells[3]);
          return event;
      });
  ```

However, with this I don't manage to remove the header line in each CSV file.

I have read that I can build a custom connector for reading CSV files by using  `createInput()` or `addSource ()` methods on the StreamExecutionEnvironment class.

Can you help with some guidance on how to achieve this, as I haven't found any examples beyond the Javadoc?

Comment: I have re-edited the question to be more precise. Is it ok to post it now? Thanks!

Comment: Much better, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could chain a filter function before your map function to filter out header lines

```
inputStream.filter(new FilterFunction<String>() {
    public boolean filter(String line) { 
        if (line.contains("some header identifier")) return false;
        else return true;
    }
}).map(...)     <Your map function as before>
```